# Why tableView reloadData doesn't call cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have two ViewControllers:

An UIViewController with a "push" button, Another UIViewController with a tableView.

PushAction

```
- (IBAction)pushViewController:(id)sender {
    NSArray *dataArr = @[@1,@2,@3,@4,@5];

    NextViewController *nextViewController = [[NextViewController alloc] init];
    [nextViewController setDataAndReload:dataArr];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
}
```

NextViewController.h

```
@interface NextViewController : UIViewController

- (void)setDataAndReload:(NSArray *)dataArr;

@end
```

NextViewController.m

```
#import "NextViewController.h"

@interface NextViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation NextViewController {
    NSMutableArray *_arr;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
 }

- (void)setDataAndReload:(NSArray *)dataArr {
    //[self loadViewIfNeeded];
    _arr = [dataArr mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

 #pragma mark - data source
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _arr.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %@", _arr[indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [_arr removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableView *)tableView {
    if (!_tableView) {
        _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        _tableView.delegate = self;
        _tableView.dataSource = self;
        _tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    return _tableView;
}
```

[image: TableView is visible]

You have noticed that I called `[self.tableView reloadData]` **before tableView was added to any view**

Then, when I select any cell on the tableView, which will call `[self.tableView reloadData]` after selected, the tableView doesn't reload as expected.

After debugging with adding some breakpoints to tableView's dataSource methods, I found that `numberOfRowsInSection:` has been called correctly, but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` has **not** been called.

Then I think what cause the issue maybe is that  `setDataAndReload:` call `[self.tableView reloadData]` before I added the tableView to viewController's view. So I added `[self loadViewIfNeeded]` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` **was called correctly.**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [_arr removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Thus, I wonder why `cellForRowAtIndexPath` can not be called after `[self.tableView reloadData]` **in the tableView's delegate method** `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: BTW, I init the tableView with `self.view.bounds`. And it make tableView's frame was wrong after it has been displayed. I think it might be a possible cause but I still can't figure out why. You should the lazy method in my posted code `[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStyleGrouped] `

Comment: Plus,  I forget to add ` [self.tableView reloadData]` in `viewDidLoad` in my demo 's code , I have edit the question, and it's not what cause the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what cause `cellForRowAtIndexPath` can not be called after `[self.tableView reloadData]`

When I call `[self.tableView reloadData]` in `setDataAndReload:` It will call the lazy method of tableView.

As I used `self.view.bounds` to initialize the table view, an at the first time `setDataAndReload:` was called, the view has not been loaded. So it will load as below (while the tableView has not been created and returned)
:

`loadView` -> `viewDidLoad` -> `[self.view addSubview:self.tableView]` -> lazy method agian

-> return second tableView

-> `self.tableView` is the second tableView

-> second tableView is added to superView

-> return first tableView

-> `self.tableView` is  the first tableView

Thus, the tableView that `self.tableView` finally pointed to, was never added to a superView!

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting your in `- (void)setDataAndReload:(NSArray *)dataArr`, like you sad, the `tableView` is not even initialised and not part of the view hierarchy. so i would recommend to rename the method to `- (void)setData:(NSArray *)dataArr` and reload the tableView in `viewDidLoad` only.

So here is your the updated code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
 }

- (void)setDataAndReload:(NSArray *)dataArr {
    _arr = [dataArr mutableCopy];
}
```

Comment: Well, I know it will solve the problem, and like I said, `[self loadViewIfNeeded]` can also solve it without changing the public interface. However, I want to know why it works.

Comment: are you using storyboards?

Comment: @dirtydanee No, I was not using storyboard  at `NextViewController`

Answer (score 0):

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, if the tableView doesn't reloadData.You should check the caller `self.tableView`, it must have some problem. And you will find the `self.tableView` has change its pointer to a new `tableView`. Then you should check your getter method. In getter method, if we want to use some properties, we must be careful.Because sometimes we may be call the getter more than once,Why?. In your example, you try to get the bounds from `self.view`, and `self.view` will send message to `-(void)loadView;` ,which is the lifecycle method of VC, and `-(void)loadView` will send message to `-(void)viewDidLoad;` Now, `-(void)viewDidLoad` call the `self.tableView` again. Fortuantely, it doesn't cause a loop.